# C++ non-blocking reading

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, nonblocking

All I need to do is just to read all available bytes from socket. But there is one condition: there is a method which reads n bytes from non-blocking socket which I have to use for implementation of another method which is going to read all available bytes.

Non-blocking reading of some data with defined size:

```
ssize_t read(void* buf, size_t len)
{
    ssize_t bytesRead = 0;
    ssize_t bytesTotallyRead = 0;
    size_t bytesLeftToRead = len;
    while (bytesTotallyRead < len)
    {
        bytesRead = ::recv(handle, (char*)buf+bytesTotallyRead, bytesLeftToRead, 0);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            bytesTotallyRead += bytesRead;
            bytesLeftToRead -= bytesRead;
        }
        else if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (bytesRead < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EINTR)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                int selectStatus(waitForIncomingData(500));
                if (selectStatus > 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return (bytesRead==-1)?-1:bytesTotallyRead;
}
```

So I have to use this method to implement something like `ssize_t readAllAvailable(std::vector<uint8_t> &data)` which uses method above for it's implementation.

The problem here, as you see, that `read()` uses `select()` for waiting for incoming data so using of buffer of fixed size (in loop) might lead to 500 ms (in this concrete case) waiting after 1st iteration and this is definitely not the way it should be done.

Is it possible at all? I mean some efficient ways.

Comment: If you need to wait on `EWOULDBLOCK`, this is not non-blocking nor asynchronous.

Comment: NB 'Non-blocking' and 'asynchronous' are not the same thing, and this code in effect is neither.

Answer (score 2):

> there is a method which reads n bytes from socket asynchronously

No there isn't. There is a method which uses non-blocking mode and `select()` to reimplement blocking mode. There is nothing 'asynchronous' about it whatsoever. From the point of view of the caller it is blocking-mode. It is poorly, indeed incorrectly, conceived, and should be thrown away. The code you have posted is completely and utterly pointless. It's just a complicated way of implementing a blocking read loop. Use blocking mode. In effect, you already are, but with more system calls. And lose the `select()` call and EAGAIN/EWOUDLBLOCK stuff.

> which I have to use for implementation of another method which is going to read all available bytes.
>   ...
>   The problem here, as you see, that read() uses select() for waiting for incoming data so using of buffer of fixed size (in loop) might lead to 500 ms (in this concrete case) waiting after 1st iteration

No it isn't. `select()` will return immediately data becomes available on the socket. No 500ms unless there is no data. And 'using a buffer of fixed size' has exactly nothing to do with it.

> and this is definitely not the way it should be done.

It isn't the way it is done.

There is no problem here to solve.

Comment: So what is the best way of reading all available bytes in blocking mode? Using ioctl(FIONREAD), select (epoll isn't available on some OS') or what? And what if I send request, then wait for response but OS buffer is still empty (because server didn't yet send all the bytes) and ioctl(FIONREAD) returns 0? How should it be properly implemented in blocking mode with minimal system calls?

Comment: You don't need anything more than `recv()`. It will block until at least one byte is available, or EOS or an error occurs, otherwise will return as many bytes as are available. Just as it says in the documentation. You don't need `ioctl(), select(), epoll()`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know the exact size of incoming data (I receive text response, parse it, etc). So I can't just read fixed bytes, because it can't be either too much or just not enough. And yes, I know there is nothing like "too much" in this case because it would simply read all available data, but in my case server messages size can be dozens of megabytes.

Comment: So what is the `len` parameter for, then? The code you posted reads up to `len` bytes. So would a non-blocking `recv()` with `len` as the third parameter, and a suitably sized buffer as the second parameter. And you stated that the 'only problem' with that code was the non-existent 500ms wait. So what exactly *is* the problem?

Comment: After you posted your comment, we started to discuss another problem. I still need to read all available data from socket, but it's better to do it in blocking mode (and thanks for your advice) in my case. So ok, now I still have to do something like `ssize_t readAllAvailable(std::vector<uint8_t> &data)`. Because I don't know the incoming message size and it varies (from dozen bytes to dozen megabytes). So my question is: what is the best way of reading all available bytes in blocking mode? (I guess I have to call `select`, when `ioctl(finoread)` and then read a fixed data chunk via `read`).

Comment: Define 'available'. Your application protocol should tell you one way or the other what has to be read at each point, either via a length-word prefix, a type-length-value system, a self-describing protocol such as XML, Java Serialization, ...

Comment: It is something like IMAP: you send some request and reply contains text strings. EOF of reply is a line (with '\n' at the end) with some special prefix or something like that. So after sending request you can give 100 % there will be some reply.