# Best way of reading all available bytes from socket in blocking mode, C++

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

What is the best way of reading from blocking socket all available bytes? 'Available' means that server response is a bunch of text lines (each with '\n') and EOF is a line with some prefix. Length of this response is always different, so I don't know it before reading. I assume using `select()` (`poll`, `epoll`) and then `'ioctl(FIONREAD)'` is the best way, am I right? Or may be just reading all available at that moment, then checking if EOF is reached and if not, then repeating all again? Yes, it sounds more rational. Does it all make any sense? So, what is the most efficient way?

Comment: Hi slowcheetah,

Personally, I'll recommend going with epoll. Epoll will notify you whenever the data available at the FD. You internally maintain a buffer in client and store the value read from the server. From the buffer, you can have your validations.

Comment: What is the problem with the traditionnals blocking *read until EOF* or non blocking *select read while available and stop if EOF*?

Comment: Govind Raj, thanks and yes I know about epoll benefits but my code is also supposed to work on os x, but epoll is not supported there, so I have to use select().

Comment: Serge Ballesta, I want to read entire chunk and then analyze it. In your case I have to parse it after every read and be sure EOF is reached, it's not complicated but I want some more "nice" way. Also I proposed this way in the question above.

Comment: Serge Ballesta, it's all because I want to add this method to some class, something like readAllAvailable(std::vector<uint_8t>&), but not to do it in protocol implementation. So in protocol implementation I call readAllAvailable(), get all the bytes then check if there is EOF, if not then call readAllAvailable() again. Reading chunk by chunk with analyzing it every time after that seems not so nice.

Comment: You need to understand, as per your [previous question on the same topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078613/c-non-blocking-reading), that 'read all available' is basically meaningless. What you really want to do is read until the end of the message, and only the message format can tell you where that is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing blocking reads there is little point in using `select`/`epoll`.

`ioctl(FIONREAD)` is a pretty useless call because by the time it returns more data may have arrived into the kernel socket buffer.

Blocking reads are easy: just keep `read`ing into your user-space socket buffer until the message terminator is found.

Ideally, the networking components you use should not care whether the socket is in blocking or in non-blocking mode: there should be a function that is called when the socket is ready for reading. In blocking mode you would call this function regardless of whether the socket is ready, it just blocks on `read` if no data is available.